# MySQL query with several nested JOINs

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables:

- soccer_players
- playersPoints
- soccer_fixtures

and I took me hours to build this query here:

```
SELECT * FROM `soccer_players`

INNER JOIN `playersPoints` ON `soccer_players`.player_id 
=`playersPoints`.playerID

INNER JOIN `soccer_fixtures`
    ON soccer_players.team_id = soccer_fixtures.home_team_id

WHERE soccer_fixtures.home_team_id IN (528,529,530, 531, 532, 533, 
534, 535, 536, 537, 538, 539, 540, 541, 542, 543, 544, 545)

AND soccer_fixtures.season_id = 2201
AND position != 'Coach' AND soccer_fixtures.status = "NS"
AND soccer_fixtures.game_week = 32

ORDER BY `soccer_players`.`player_name` ASC
```

and my result is good, but my problem is that I want to add after

```
INNER JOIN `soccer_fixtures`
    ON soccer_players.team_id = soccer_fixtures.home_team_id
```

this:

```
INNER JOIN `soccer_fixtures`
    ON soccer_players.team_id = soccer_fixtures.away_team_id
```

My goal is to filter football players from a table, join them with the points of these players and join this result then with the fixtures of this gameweek that I can display, which player is playing on which date.

I know what the problem is but I don't know how to solve it.

There can't be 2 `INNER JOIN`s with the same name but how can I group these two `INNER JOIN`s to one?

**EDIT:**

I have also tried the following:

```
SELECT * FROM `soccer_players`

INNER JOIN `playersPoints` ON `soccer_players`.player_id  
=`playersPoints`.playerID

INNER JOIN `soccer_fixtures`
    RIGHT JOIN soccer_players
    (
        ON soccer_fixtures.team_id = soccer_fixtures.home_team_id
        ON soccer_fixtures.team_id = soccer_fixtures.a_team_id
    )

WHERE

soccer_fixtures.home_team_id IN (528,529,530, 531, 532, 533, 
534, 535, 536, 537, 538, 539, 540, 541, 542, 543, 544, 545)

OR 

soccer_fixtures.a_team_id IN (528,529,530, 531, 532, 533, 
534, 535, 536, 537, 538, 539, 540, 541, 542, 543, 544, 545)

AND soccer_fixtures.season_id = 2201
AND position != 'Coach' AND soccer_fixtures.status = "NS"
AND soccer_fixtures.game_week = 32

ORDER BY `soccer_players`.`player_name` ASC
```

without success, but I think that's close to the solution.

**EDIT2:**

ok now I have this solution here:
the result is wonderfull! I am wondered a lil bit about the perfomance, it took really long now to get the correct result. Can i modify the query a lil bit to get the results from my 3 tabkles faster?

here is my modiefied version now:

Big Thx to Thorsten!

[image: thx to]

Comment: _nested **JOINTS**..._ you mean `JOIN` ;)

Comment: The problem is there's no Italy. ;-) -- See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I don't understand what you actually want to select. Don't just join everything and then `SELECT *`. Are `soccer_fixtures` soccer *matches*? And what is `playersPoints`? This table is not really related to `soccer_fixtures`, correct? So for a player I can find `soccer_fixtures` A and B and `PlayerPoints` 10 and 20 and the join gives me four rows, namely A-10, A-20, B-10, B-20 for the player. Is this intended?

Comment: So please show some sample data and the expected result.

Comment: my goal ist a record like this: Lionel Messi - 500 Points - but i want to select only players where the match status in our fixtures table is "NS" (for not started) and only games who are playing this gameWeek 32 for example
but all these information are in 3 different tables. And the biggest thing is, that i need a matching between the player. He got a team_id. So i have to match the fixtures.home_team_id and the fixtures.away_team_id with the player ID of the soccer_players table.

Answer (score 1):

You want to select players that have a match with status NS in week 32. So select from players. Criteria (match with status and week) belongs in the `WHERE` clause. As a player can have many points, add up each players point and outer join them to the players.

```
select sp.name, coalesce(pp.total_points, 0) as points
from soccer_players sp
left join
(
  select playerid, sum(points) as total_points
  from playerspoints 
  group by playerid
) pp on pp.playerid = sp.player_id
where exists
(
  select *
  from soccer_fixtures sf
  where sf.season_id = 2201
    and sf.game_week = 32
    and sf.status = 'NS'
    and sp.team_id in (sf.home_team_id, sf.away_team_id)
);
```

(Instead of putting the points subquery in the `FROM` clause, you can also have it in the `SELECT` clause, but generally we prefer the outer join in `FROM`, so we can select more than one column if necessary.)

Comment: Thx for Your prof. help! at the moment i am getting some errors back, but i try to fix them bymyself hold on pls ;) BUT this "where exists" and the coalesc() thing is new to me

Comment: hey Thorsten, first of all! GREAT QUERY! it gives me exacltly the players i need back....Do you have any idea, why the query took arround 30 Sek. to give me a result back? how can i optimize the performance a lil bit? becasue if our user have to wait after each filter submit so long :( that would be horrable :(

Comment: oh >> i dont know whay, but for some reason now the result was displayed really really fast... maybe something with the server was wrong! thx man!

Comment: If this query runs slow, it may be because there are no indexes to help the DBMS to quickly find the records. First of all the tables should have primary keys, e.g. player_id for table soccer_players. Then there should be foreign keys, e.g. playerspoints.playerid references soccer_players.player_id. And then you can add further indexes, e.g. on soccer_fixtures(session_id, game_week, status). Play with this composite index, the order of columns may matter. If the query is slow first and when you run it again is suddenly fast, it may be because the data is already in memory from the first run.

Comment: ah understand >> so all of my tables already have PK, so no i will try to set in these 3 tables also a FK... and then i will add then some indexes... I will get back at You again! Danke vorab ;)

Comment: You saved my day ;)